# kendo export pdf not supporting non-US currency symbols in generated PDF document

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, kendo-ui-angular2

im using kendo-ui with angular in my application, there is a need of showing created order details in a PDF with client-based currency symbols, but

```
<kendo-pdf-export #PDF [margin]="'3cm'">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="summary-heading">
      <h2>{{'orderSummary' | translate}}</h2>
    </div>

   ....
  .......
  </div>
</kendo-pdf-export>
```

has only supporting US symbol ($) , inidan currency symbol is showing as ",," which is wrong , how can add indian currency in PDF.

please help,
https://angular-uezijy.stackblitz.io here a stackblitz link which reflects the same issue.

Comment: Did you try using other fonts? It is possible that the symbol is not supported with the one you're using

Comment: Thanks, @Bertramp, yes changing the font family can help to fix this. https://www.telerik.com/forums/issues-in-export-pdf-of-grid, based on this link also,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the DejaVu Sans font family in project's main css/scss file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "DejaVuSans";
    src:url("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.k-grid {font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;}
```

able to show the INR symbol in PDF(also it support most widely used all currencies)

the updated link of https://angular-uezijy.stackblitz.io can be helpful for code level also.